# Apache NiFi: Changing Date and Time format in csv

Tags: csv, validation, apache-nifi

I have a csv which contains a column with a date and time. I want to change the format of the date-time column. The first 3 rows of my csv looks like the following.

```
Dater,test1,test2,test3,test4,test5,test6,test7,test8,test9,test10,test11
20011018182036,,,,,166366183,,,,,,
20191018182037,,27,94783564564,,162635463,817038655446,,,0,,
```

I want to change the csv to look like this.

```
Dater,test1,test2,test3,test4,test5,test6,test7,test8,test9,test10,test11
2001-10-18-18-20-36,,,,,166366183,,,,,,
2019-10-18-18-20-37,,27,94783564564,,162635463,817038655446,,,0,,
```

How is this possible?
I tried using the `UpdateRecord` Processor.

My properties look like this:

[image: Update Record Processer]

But this approach doesn't work since the data gets routed as a failure from the `UpdateRecord` Processor. Suggest me a method to complete the task.

Comment: You need https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.9.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.UpdateRecord/index.html

Comment: @daggett I read through the link you have included. I have already followed the method it asks to be followed.

Comment: Could you please explain?

Comment: @daggett I followed the guidelines in that link. So I am unable to understand what's wrong with my work flow.

Comment: With UpdateAttribute you can change flow file attributes. Such as `filename`. But you want to change content of the flow file, and `UpdateRecord` processor best matches your requirements.

Comment: @daggett I have made a mistake when typing the question. I used the `UpdateRecord` processor in my actual workflow. I have edited the question now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202624/discussion-between-himsara-gallege-and-daggett).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to accomplish this using the `UpdateRecord` Processor. The expression language I used is `${field.value:toDate('yyyyMMddHHmmss'):format('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')}`.

[image: Update Record Configuration]

Just this **didn't work** since every time, the data was routed towards the failure path from the `UpdateRecord` Processor.

***To fix this error*** I changed the configuration of the `CSVRecordSetWriter`. The **`Schema Access Strategy`** must be changed to **`Use String Fields from Header`**. This is by default `Use Schema Name Property`

Answer (score 2):

Strategy: use [**UpdateRecord**](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.9.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.UpdateRecord/additionalDetails.html) to manipulate the timestamp value using [**expression language**](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/expression-language-guide.html#format):

```
${field.value:toDate():format('ddMMyyyy')}
```

Flow:

[image]

GenerateFlowFile:

[image]

UpdateRecord:

[image]

Setup reader and writer to inherit schema. Include header line. Leave other properties untouched.

Result:

[image]

However this solution might not satisfy you because of a strange problem. When you format the date like that:

```
${field.value:toDate():format('dd-MM-yyyy')}
```

ConvertRecord routes to the failure relationship:

[image]

Type coercion does not work properly. Maybe it is a bug. I could not find a solution for this problem.

Comment: You have said to be using `${field.value:toDate():format('ddMMyyyy')}` within `UpdateRecord`. But in the screenshot you have `${field.value:toDate():format('MMddyyyy')}` within `UpdateRecord`

Comment: @HimsaraGallege yeah I mixed things up. Anyway.. you have to provide your own format string as described here https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/expression-language-guide.html#format